# Installation problems with h5ai webindex

Tags: apache, .htaccess, indexing

So i've been trying to install h5ai webindex in my webserver, but the thing is, i can't manage to install it correctly, since h5ai folders insists on showing up, when i open any folder created by me that is listed, and then refresh the page the index reverts to the apache default one. If anyone could help me through the installation process i would be very thankfull.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you modified the default index-file list, as specified on the h5ai website? It seems your problem is related to that as Apache doesn't seem to care about the h5ai index file.
Also, are you sure you rebooted your web-server?

Comment: Well, i'm trying this in a shared host webserver, more exactly OVH, and yes, i've changed the .htaccess and added the lines as said in the h5ai website.

Comment: And if you please thoroughly guide me through the installation, and to get on showing up just what i want to, i would be very appreciated.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think OVH allows this in its shared hosting offers.